# How can I set download limit for my macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite

How can I set download limit for my macbook? my internet speed is 1mb/s how can I use only 500kb/s I use OS X Yosemite

Comment: This is not generally possible. You may, however, be able to set it for certain specific software, or you may be able to limit your speed for all connections, not just downloads.

Answer (score 0):

There's a developer download for Hardware IO Tools that includes a preference pane for [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/), under which you can create a custom profile to specify how you want your network to behave:

[image: some profile set to download 500 kbps]

It's more than likely you don't want it to drop packets or add delay.

You can [register for free to access Apple developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action) and [download Apple's Hardware IO Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=Network%20Link%20Conditioner).

Don't forget to turn of the Network Link Conditioner when you're somewhere with better bandwidth access.

It's intended to allow developers to emulate various types of network connections so they understand the impact on their users.

Also see the man page for pfctl which is Apple's successor to ipfw. Also the man page for pf.conf.

Comment: thanks but it looks to difficult to make that. I will try when I will very need this